# AOT Compile error when trying to serialize custom object using ServiceStack on Monotouch

Tags: json, rest, xamarin.ios, servicestack

I'm trying to serialize an object using servicestack in monotouch and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the classes to be available when doing an AOT build for the device.  The build works fine for the simulator.  I have the latest version of Monotouch, and latest version of the Monotouch ServiceStack library, which I pulled and built myself this morning.

What I'm trying to do is call the generic ToJson() to serialize model object (called Note below) of mine. All of my web service models / service calls / serialization / deserialization happen inside of a class library external to my iphone and android app, in which I am trying to call the JsConfig.RegisterForAot() and JsConfig.RegisterTypeForAot(), which seems to not help.  I'm also calling those methods inside my iphone app since I'm unsure if both locations are necessary.

Error/Stack trace:

```
Attempting to JIT compile method 'ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteListsOfElements`2<int, ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer>:WriteListValueType (System.IO.TextWriter,object)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.


  at ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteType`2[MyClassLibrary.Note,ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer].WriteProperties (System.IO.TextWriter writer, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString (System.Object value, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString[Object] (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Text.StringExtensions.ToJson[Object] (System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyClassLibrary.Utils.ObjectToJson (System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyClassLibrary.Utils.AddObjectToData (System.Net.WebRequest request, System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyClassLibrary.Utils.SendJsonRequest[Note] (System.String url, System.String httpVerb, MyClassLibrary.Note obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyClassLibrary.Note.JSONSave () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at iphoneapp.myViewController.SaveNote () [0x000a5] in /Users/myUser/Projects/iphoneapp/iphoneapp/ViewControllers/myViewController.cs:83 

Exact target/types:
ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteType`2[[MyClassLibrary.Note, MyClassLibraryName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer, ServiceStack.Text.MonoTouch, Version=3.8.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into a few of these problems and the issue usually came down to the use of enums in some of my DTO properties.

What you need to do is force initialisation of the generic serializer for each enum explicitly for the AOT compiler.
The way I do this is to create a bunch of dummy serializers (I don't do anything with them) in my AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching code:

```
// AOT register enums that are involved in service DTOs
var dummy1 = new JsonSerializer<MyEnum>();
var dummy2 = new JsonSerializer<MyOtherEnum>();
```

If you are only using the JSON side then you should have some success with the approach above.

I have some cases where I serialise lists into a single string property, so I also initialise the JsvSerialiser in the same way as above.

The key is to explicitly create serializers for your enums in code, so that the AOT compiler has something to find and compile ahead.

Comment: Thanks, but This didn't work for me. I added these for the model to be serialized and any objects/enums that it has as properties/uses.  It still blows up on 

WriteListsOfElements`2<int,      ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer>:WriteListValueType (System.IO.TextWriter,object)'

Which I can't add a hint to because it is internal to the ServiceStack library

Comment: Actually you were right! I didn't give it a hint for List<int> but I did for int.  The AOT compiler was removing the serializer for List<int>.  I added the following line var dummy = new JsonSerializer<List<int>>();  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Ok I'm going to look like an idiot... that didn't fix it, I've had a long day... I had the line of code that was assigning a value to the list<int> commented out.  To fix the problem I ended up changing my property that was a list<int> to a list<string> and now it does work. If I had more time I'd look into how to get the aot to retain the WriteListOfElements<int...

Comment: Its been a while, but I also have modified the JsConfig.RegisterForAot() method in the SS source code.
I can't remember exactly what I did and don't have the time to go through it, but heres the JsConfig source for you to have a look at.
https://gist.github.com/3758928

Comment: I have quite a few other types that will need to be serialized so I might have to reference this in the future for some ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

maybe `WriteListsOfElements2<int, ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer>` is a clue. Perhaps you need to create a dummy as suggested by Paul DB for a list of integers.

Comment: You only are saying this because you are in the cube next to me and just heard me explain the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // this is required for MT AOT compiler
        JsConfig.RegisterTypeForAot<YourEnumHere>();
```

...

With the latest version of Xamarin.iOS I have found that this is not required anymore.